# MethodInfo.Invoke parameter order

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to invoke a method using reflection.

Something like this:

```
method.Invoke(instance, propValues.ToArray())
```

The problem is that there isn't a way to ensure the array of parameters is in the right order. Is there a way to specific which values goes on which parameter by name? Or do I really have to make a custom binder? If so, can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to specific which values goes on which parameter by name?

Well, you specify them in parameter order. So if you want to map specific values to specific names, you should fetch the parameter list with [`method.GetParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters.aspx) and map them that way. For example, if you had a `Dictionary<string, object>` with the parameters:

```
var arguments = method.GetParameters()
                      .Select(p => dictionary[p.Name])
                      .ToArray();
method.Invoke(instance, arguments);
```

Comment: I will not be able to use it due to some complications regarding the ASP.NET MVC framework. However, this 100% answered the question. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this approach, but keep getting "The given key was not present in the dictionary."
What am I missing?

Comment: @Jacques: Well that would suggest that there's a parameter which you haven't specified in your dictionary...

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the quick feedback. Not sure how I can show you the code properly formatted other than in this comment: 
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(command, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string,object>();
var parameters = method.GetParameters()
                        .Select(p => dictionary[p.Name])
                        .ToArray();
//the previous line is where I get the exception. 
So I used your code pretty much as is apart from declaring the dictionary which I wasn't sure about.

Comment: @Jacques: Well you're creating a new dictionary there - that hasn't got any values in. Where do you expect it to get the values from? If that doesn't help, I suggest you ask a new question with a short but complete example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JonSkeet. Yeah from your example I wasn't sure how to instantiate the dictionary?

Comment: @Jacques: Well the question assumes that you have the argument values you want to pass, but you only know them by parameter name. I've no idea what you've got in your situation - it may well be nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've created a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680043/use-reflection-to-execute-a-method-with-parameters-raising-exception-in-getparam 
Hopefully that explains my situation a bit better and sorry for the run around.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This answer focuses on parameter types not the parameter names. If the code is obfuscated (or having different param names) then it will be difficult to map the solution that Jon Skeet has provided.

Anyway, I had been playing with this a lot.... This is what works best for me (without knowing param names) :

```
    public object CallMethod(string method, params object[] args)
    {
        object result = null;

        // lines below answers your question, you must determine the types of 
        // your parameters so that the exact method is invoked. That is a must!
        Type[] types = new Type[args.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
        {
            if (args[i] != null)
                types[i] = args[i].GetType();
        }

        MethodInfo _method = this.GetType().GetMethod(method, types);

        if (_method != null)
        {
            try
            {
                _method.Invoke(this, args);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // instead of throwing exception, you can do some work to return your special return value

                throw ex;
            }
        }

        return result;

    }
```

so, you can call the above function:

```
    object o = CallMethod("MyMethodName", 10, "hello", 'a');
```

The above call will should be able to invoke this method with matching signature:

```
public int MyMethodName(int a, string b, char c) {
   return 1000;
}
```

Please note that he above example is in the scope of '`this`'

Comment: You'll still be broken if there are multiple parameters with the same type though...

Comment: Even if there are same types, the correct method will be invoked. Trust me, you should try it.

Comment: Having reread your answer, I believe you've missed the point of the question entirely. The example you've given has the arguments in the right order. The OP's whole problem is that the arguments *aren't* necessarily in the right order. He's already got the right method, but he doesn't know how to pass the arguments so that they correspond with the parameters.

Comment: Well, I explained how the methods can be invoked on the basis of parameter types. In your case, if the code is obfuscated and you have different parameter names then it wont be possible to map the values to exact parameter.

Comment: You're still missing my point: you're assuming the problem is finding the right method, but there's nothing about the question which suggests that's the case. It's all about the order of the arguments, and your answer doesn't help with that *at all*.