# Use reflection to execute a method with parameters raising Exception in GetParameters

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a console app that I'm testing the basic ability to enter a command such as: 
**Edit**

```
AddUser id=1 name=John surname=Doe
```

**Edit**
The hypothetical method AddUser could look like this:

```
public AddUser(int id, string name, string surname
{
    //add code here to add user
}
```

Here's my code:

```
protected void Process(string command)
{
    //get the type
    Type type = this.GetType(); 

    //do a split on the command entered
    var commandStructure = command.Split(' ');

    try
    {
        //reassign the command as only the method name
        command = commandStructure[0];

        //remove the command from the structure
        commandStructure = commandStructure.Where(s => s != command).ToArray();

        //get the method
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(command, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        //if the method was found
        if (method != null)
        {
            Dictionary<string, ParameterInfo> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, ParameterInfo>();

            //**Here's where I get the exception that the key was not found in the** 
            //**dictionary**
            var parameters = method.GetParameters()
                .Select(p => dictionary[p.Name])
                .ToArray();

            //add code here to apply values found in the command to parameters found
            //in the command
            //...

            method.Invoke(this, parameters);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("No such command exists man! Try again.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Prompt();
        Wait();
    }
}
```

[I was trying to understand the stack answer provided by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527345/methodinfo-invoke-parameter-order/11527470#comment38259909_11527470) but couldn't get it working. I assume this is because I'm misunderstanding the discussion or use of his example.

So my question is: How do I get a list of parameters populated with the values entered by the user in the command prompt? The method part works, I'm successfully running methods that have no parameters, but when I added the code to handle parameters it got complicated.

Comment: How does `GetUser` method definition look like?

Comment: The error is fairly straightforward.  You're trying to get the value of a key that isn't in your dictionary.  We know it's not in your dictionary because you've never added *anything* to your dictionary.

Comment: Hint: why are you modifying `commandStructure` and then not reading from it again?

Comment: @KonradKokosa I've edited the question to add a clearer method that would be called

Comment: @Servy thanks, I guess I'm struggling to understand how I could map the parameters provided in the command to parameters required by the method. I've updated the question to give a hypothetical Method that would be called

Comment: Your dictionary should be of type `Dictionary<string, object>`.  It should have your parameters in it.  For example, dictionary entry with key "Id" should have a value of 1

Comment: @JonSkeet I modify command structure to remove the first element in the array after splitting it which is the actual method name. What remains after that is the parameters the user is entering in the console

Comment: @Jacques: Indeed. (Although `.Skip(1)` would be simpler.) My point is that you're not doing anything with the variable afterwards. What's the point of performing a modification if you're not going to read the result?

Comment: @JonSkeet I had no particular reason for it apart from separating out the Method name and leaving only parameters in the commandStructure.

Comment: I don't know how many different ways I can say this... you're separating out the parameters and then completely ignoring them. Look at the code: try to work out where you're *using* the parameters. (Hint: you're not. That's why you're getting an error.)

Comment: @JonSkeet It could be that I DON"T understand how this should be done. If you look at my code there's a section that I've just left as comments (//add code here) that is where I intended to use the remaining commandStructure vars. My understanding is that I first need to get a list of Parameters from the method then somehow populate them with the values from the command structure array. But, it was failing before I could even get there. If I'm missing the point, let me know, I'd be glad to understand it better.

Comment: @Jacques: Yes, the comment comes *after* the error. You need to change the code *before* that, to convert your `commandStructure` info a relevant name/value dictionary. It sounds like you might be in over your head, to be honest..

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the input Jon. No more needed thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is get a dictionary of the parameters that you can use, if your initial string contained a comma seperated list of parameters you could get it by doing something like this

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = commandStructure[1].Split(',')
.ToDictionary(x => x.Split('=').First(), x => x.Split('=').Last());
```

But note the dictionary's value here is of type "string", because the inputs are coming in as string.

This would take an input such as

```
"GetUser id=1,name=tom,path=C"
```

And convert it to a dictionary with the keys "id", "name" and "path", and the values as "1", "tom" and "C".  Then when you do

```
var parameters = method.GetParameters()
            .Select(p => dictionary[p.Name])
            .ToArray();
```

You will get an array of the values needed, which can be passed to method.Invoke();

**Alternatively:** If your original parameter list was seperated by spaces then your original "Split" statement would have split these, so now your commandStructure array would contain the method name and the parameters.  The dictionary method would become:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = commandStructure.Skip(1)
.ToDictionary(x => x.Split('=').First(), x => x.Split('=').Last());
```

Comment: for clarity sake what if the command parameters were separated by spaces e.g.e "AddUser id=1 name=john surname=doe
?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
dictionary = method.GetParameters()
                   .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x);
```

in place of exception. But not sure why do you need it.

Comment: Thanks that does get me the dictionary, but I guess your question does make me think. What I need is to map the parameters passed into the command to the parameters expected by the Method. So this would require: 
1. The ability to convert the command parameters to the correct type expected by the Method parameters
2. The ability to make sure all the parameters were specified (or I could just rely on an exception for this)